# Placing / while calling servlet in jsp form

Tags: forms, jsp, servlets, struts

Will there be any impact if I replace

```
<form action ="someaction.do">
```

with

```
<form action="/someaction.do">
```

Is there any difference between those two codes? What if I palce "/" for calling action servlet ? What happens If I wont place "/"?.

Actually I am converting my website from http to https. Now While migrating , 
Some pages are working fine If i use 2nd method (i.e with using /) Some pages are not working If don't use/.

Any ideas why?

Answer (score 0):

This is less of a servlet question, and moreso an HTML general question, but essentially, lets say your current url is something like this:
`http://mywebsite.com/somedir/index.jsp`

If you have a form with your action being `someaction.do`, it will look for
`http://mywebsite.com/somedir/someaction.do`
This is known as a **relative** path.

If it starts with a /, it's considered an **absolute** path, and will look for
`http://mywebsite.com/someaction.do`

Answer (score 0):

To avoid these problem specify your serverlt like this:

EL:

```
<form action="${pageContext.request.contextPath}/someaction.do" >
```

Scriptlet:

```
<form action='<%=request.getContextPath( )%>/someaction.do' >
```

Assuming all the servlets are correctly mapped in the `web.xml`.